# getting path of programdata in Visual Studio setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, setup-project

Is there anyway I can get the path of **programdata** folder dynamically in a setup project in  the very same way I get the path of **program files** folder by using the keyword [Program Files] as defaultlocation for custom folder?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about setup projects, or some other setup technology?

Comment: I'm asking about Visual Studio setup project. When I add a custom folder,I can set its path as [Program Files]\foldername.
Sameway,how do I set the path as [ProgramData]\foldername? Is there any short form to get the actual path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CommonAppDataFolder] - for c:\ProgramData or "all users\application data"

[ApplicationData] - for user specific application data folder in roaming profile

[LocalApplicationData] - for user specific application data folder in local profile

Comment: [CommonApplicationData] isn't copying into programdata...but the keywords are useful....thanks :)